# What is the inspiration for Rappaccini’s daughter in the same-named novel

Tags: inspiration

What was the inspiration behind Beatrice, the titular character in Nathaniel Hawthorne's novel *Rappacinni's Daughter*?

Comment: Presumably the answer is the folkloric Visha Kanya, directly or otherwise.

Comment: "*The traditional story of a poisonous maiden has been traced back to India, and Hawthorne's version has been adopted in contemporary works*" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rappaccini%27s_Daughter

Comment: And - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rappaccini%27s_Daughter#Sources

Comment: @Valorum The only reason I didn't paste that verbatim into the answer field is because it mostly lacks original sources and... wikipedia. :)

Comment: @DavidW - Well, yes. Hence why it's a comment rather than a lazy-as-f answer